# Why is the result of stream-cons not a valid input to stream-empty? in Racket

Tags: stream, racket

When I run the following code, I get the indicated error message. I'd appreciate help in understanding why *stream-cons* apparently doesn't produce a result that *stream-empty?* can process. Thanks.

```
> (stream-empty? (stream-cons 0 empty-stream))
. . stream-empty?: contract violation
  expected: stream?
  given: '(0 . #<promise:unsaved-editor:14:46>)
```

Comment: Works fine for me (yields `#f`). What language are you using? Which version of Racket?

Comment: I'm using DrRacket 6.2.1

Comment: Me too.  `#lang racket`.

Comment: I didn't do the import (require racket/stream), but no message wrt undefined was generated. With the import it works. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use any `import`. It works with and without.

Comment: Don't know. I'm using #lang racket.  With (require  racket/stream) commented out, I get the indicated error. With it in, I get an error on "Run" saying "module: identifier is already imported in: stream-cons", but the example runs fine.

Comment: FWIW It works in 6.3.0.

Comment: Anyone have any idea why I get the error indicated above with `stream-cons`?

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723927/why-is-the-result-of-stream-cons-not-a-valid-input-to-stream-empty-in-racket#comment55217454_33723927), you defined your own version of `stream-cons`. This version of `stream-cons` produces a stream-like object that is not compatible with Racket streams. (That is, `stream?` returns false for your faux-streams.)

If you want to create your own faux-streams, you will need to create your own `stream-empty?`, `stream?`, and other stream-related procedures, that work with your streams rather than standard Racket streams.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was misleading. I didn't define my own stream-cons.

Comment: @RussAbbott Did you include any modules that did redefine it? You may wish to post your code in a Gist and link it here, because that error message does imply that it was redefined one way or another.

Comment: I wish I had kept it. It was just a temporary bunch of experimental code.